# Launch mobile safari from full screen web app on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I've Googled this question in a few variations and can only find answers in the context of using PhoneGap or jQuery mobile. However, I'm using neither... just plain old html and javascript.

I'm trying to launch mobile safari from a full screen web app using window.open()... not an inline anchor. No matter what I do, the url opens in the web app, not in Safari. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while but I was able to piece this solution together. In an iOS standalone web app mode, it creates a link element using jQuery, adds it to the body, simulates a click on it, and then removes the link. You can accomplish the same thing without jQuery, it just takes more code using the naive DOM methods.

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
  var $a = $('<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"/>');
  $("body").append($a);

  var a = $a.get(0);

  var mouseEvent = a.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  mouseEvent.initMouseEvent('click');
  a.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);

  $a.remove();
}
else {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 4.3, the only way I know of is to convert the `<div>` into an `<a target="_blank">` and let the default browser to handler it. It launches the new page into an external Safari.

Comment: Its not working for me...Can you me a sample htmlString which I can load only my web view and it will open safari when clicked

Comment: Also I am checking on a simulator I hope that won't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

In PhoneGap, all URLs load into WebView by default. Setting targets or being fancy with JS will not break your external links out of that WebView. In order to load external URLs into Safari, rather than the PhoneGap app itself, you need to modify the way URLs are handled in the application delegate.

Open up your PhoneGap app code and locate [projectname]AppDelegate.m ... typically found under [projectname]/Classes folder.

Modify shouldStartLoadWithRequest however you like.  Here is a sample implementation that will evaluate requests and handle HTTP or HTTPS schemes to load in Safari (borrowed from http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/02/15/open-external-links-in-safariapp/):

```c
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];

    // Intercept the external http requests and forward to Safari.app
    // Otherwise forward to the PhoneGap WebView
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Worked perfectly. Also, for those looking in `AppDelegate.m` without success, note that in later versions of PhoneGap/Apache Cordova, including 1.8.0, the generated override of the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method has been commented out and moved to the bottom of `MainViewController.m`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `window.openNative()`?

Comment: It's interesting when you try the various URL Scheme options. Mail links launch the mail app, Map links launch the map app, etc. But a plain old http://www url does not launch Safari.

Answer (score 0):

can't you use a normal A HREF Tag? this normally opens Safari from within a webapp.

Comment: If you can use an <a> tag with target="_blank" it will be ok. But if you are in a situation in which you cannot use an A tag, you'll need to use that solution.

Comment: There are many situations in which you cannot use an <a> tag. For example:
- programmatically open a link
- HTML5 mobile apps (frameworks like Sencha Touch 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create a standard HTML link , but you must open Safari programmatically (with Javascript code only), here is the code:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href', facebook);
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
a.click();
```